# Duplicate Content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have a client that is a Tour Operator. They have a wordpress custom post type for tours, that include a description of the tour, flight and other journey details and the itenary. Since there are more then one date for a tour, they  just duplicate  tour posts for a tour to accomodate the different dates. They dont want to implement one post with tabs for the different dates, as minisucule but important information such as hotels and flight details can change from date to date. I can canonicalise different posts for different dates of the same tour - Is that the best solution I have ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead having a list of tour dates run down the right side of the page. Each set of available dates links to a page that describes the same tour. In addition to that information, include details that are specific to that date:

- availability or full
- average weather conditions
- what to pack
- what they might not want to forget

If you frequently entertain visitors from other regiions, it might be worthwhile to include:

- what type of power outlets to expect, and
- the current exchange rate

If your average customer remains in the area before and after the tour, exchanging links with the local eateries, hotels, area attractions, and seasonal events, can be beneficial (both for business and SEO/SERP positions).

By adding additional information to your page(s), you can balance the negative issue of duplicate pages with details that vary (even slightly) and benefit your customers.